# Need to delete minikube from centos7

Tags: linux, kubernetes, centos7, minikube

i deleted minikube using minikube delete --all command

and when type minikube version appears and the command still works

how to delete any thing related to minikube and kubectl also

Comment: Did you try purge with apt get?

Answer (score -1):

if you downloaded minikube binary file, just delete the file. minikube working just binary file and don`t use specific dependencies for lib. but minikube use virtlib tool for vm orchestration.

you can delete minikube binary file this way:

```bash
rm $(which minikube)
rm $(which kubectl)
```

if you delete virtlib and all not usable dependencies on centos, run

```bash
yum autoremove qemu-kvm libvirt libvirt-python libguestfs-tools virt-install
```